# Procedure or function EmployeeInsert has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting the error

> Procedure or function EmployeeInsert has too many arguments specified.

My stored procedure is this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeInsert]
    @Surname varchar(50),
    @Name varchar(50),
    @Gender varchar(10),
    @City varchar(50),
    @Address varchar(150),
    @DateOfAdding datetime,
    @DateOfUpdating datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewEmpCode varchar(5);
    DECLARE @CodeTemp int 

    SELECT @CodeTemp = MAX(CAST(RIGHT([EmployeeCode], 3) AS INT)) 
    FROM Employee

    SELECT @CodeTemp = CASE WHEN @CodeTemp IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE  @CodeTemp+1 END 

    SELECT @NewEmpCode = 'A'+RIGHT(('0'+CAST(@CodeTemp AS VARCHAR(5))),3)

    INSERT INTO Employee 
    VALUES(@NewEmpCode, @Surname, @Name, @Gender, @City, @Address, @DateOfAdding, @DateOfUpdating)
END
```

And I am defining the parameters for this stored procedure like this:

```
public int InsertEmployee(Employee empObj)
{
    SqlDateTime getDate = SqlDateTime.Null;
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.InsertCommand = con.CreateCommand();
    sda.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sda.InsertCommand.CommandText = "EmployeeInsert";

    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewEmpCode", empObj.EmployeeCode);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", empObj.Surname);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", empObj.Name);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", empObj.Gender);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", empObj.City);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", empObj.Address);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfAdding", DateTime.Now);
    sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfUpdating", getDate);

    int i = sda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return i;
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You're defining a `@NewEmpCode` parameter - but your stored procedure doesn't have this parameter - that's why the error says: "too many parameters defined"....."

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Thanks Mr. Marc_s for coming with help for my problem.I am new here on Stack overflow.I think it is my second question which I asked here.Actually from this stored procedure I am trying to add auto incremented VARCHAR EmployeeCode and I think I have declared here in the stored procedure  @NewEmpCode varchar(5).and in parameters also I tried from Add() method also but bad luck in this way also it is not working.

Comment: Ask this as a proper question ....